# Handle build-time generated .class files in maven

Tags: java, class, maven

In a maven projet I have a very specific plugin (jsweet-maven-plugin) that dynamically generates .class files at build time, from the declared dependencies. I need those .class files to be in the build path, for maven as well as for the IDE (for autocompletion).

Is there a way to handle it properly in maven ?

The best I could come up with was to do a dedicated maven module that packages those .class in a jar, then add that jar as a dependency to my other project. That way those .class are properly added to the build path.

However this method fails in netbeans IDE because the IDE sees the dependency as a project present in the computer. Instead of decompiling the .class, it seeks the sources in the related project and fails since there are no sources... Until i change the version of the project and that the IDE relies on the jar and not the sources anymore.

I'd love a generated-classes folder behaving the same way as generated-sources, but for class files... Is there a maven-guru that would know a way ?

---

Edit 1 : The files generated at build time are not java source code, but already compiled files (.class extention) : bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. Generate your classes once, and copy the generated .java files up into your src/main/java tree, and comment out the auto-generation stuff in pom.xml. This has the advantage that you can add behavioural and toString() methods to your generated classes, and the IDE autocomplete is happy. The downside is if you need to generate again, then there can be a fair bit of merging to do.
2. Create a separate library as you have done. Install the library in your Maven repository and make sure the Java source is uploaded as well. Close the project in the IDE. (This works in Eclipse - I expect Netbeans would behave similarly).

I have tried both, and always come back to option 1. But I am usually generating JAXWS classes from a WSDL. Your exact requirement is unfamiliar to me, so best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I already know how to handle properly generated sources like a client generated from WSDL.
However the problem here is that this is not java source code that is generated, but .class files (bytecode).